# Error message xy should be of class SpatialPoints

Tags: arguments, frame, spatial, points

I am running an MCP (home-range) analysis in R on my data (called Ade) which is a set of GPS points for animal locations.

I ran the following script:

```
Ade <- read.csv("Ade.csv")
#Get the folder SP that is used to convert the data
library(sp)
#Convert 
Ade <- matrix(runif(1564), ncol=2)
head (Ade)
Ade <- data.frame(Ade)
#Convert Ade to spatial points data frame by first ...
#Tell R that the coordinates are in the column X and column Y
coords <- SpatialPoints(Ade[, c("X", "Y")])
AdeSpat <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords, Ade)
#Specify the coordinate reference system of the data
proj4string(AdeSpat) <- CRS("+proj=XY +ellps=WGS84")
#View data
getClass(AdeSpat)
class(AdeSpat)
head (AdeSpat)
#Two steps in loading AdehabitatHR into R
install.packages("adehabitatHR")
library(adehabitatHR)
#Run MCP
mcp <- mcp(AdeSpat$coordinates, percent=95, unin = c ("km"), unout = c("km2"))
```

BUT when I run this I get the following error message:

```
Error in mcp(AdeSpat$coordinates, percent = 95, unin = c("km"), unout =   
c("km2")) : xy should be of class SpatialPoints
```

Can someone explain to me what this means, and how I can resolve the issue, I have searched on the internet but cannot find any answer for the error "xy should be of class SpatialPoints".

When I check the data frame I get the following output:

```
> class(AdeSpat)
[1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"

> head (AdeSpat)
    coordinates ID ZONE      X       Y
1 (370984, 9752290)  1 36 M 370984 9752293
2 (370980, 9752290)  2 36 M 370980 9752288
3 (370980, 9752290)  3 36 M 370980 9752288
4 (370995, 9752290)  4 36 M 370995 9752287
5 (370995, 9752290)  5 36 M 370995 9752287
6 (371032, 9752310)  6 36 M 371032 9752312
Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: +proj=XY +ellps=WGS84
```

Thank you J

Answer (score 0):

You have to put directly the object who contains your Spatial Points data.

In you case, your formula will be:

mcp <- mcp(coords, percent=95, unin = c ("km"), unout = c("km2"))

I hope that it will help you!

Murielle